# redirect to another html page with script tag

Tags: javascript

i am trying to redirect to another html page using

```
window.confirm('Login was successful')
        {
window.location.href="logintest.html";
};
```

but it is not working. this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Instructor Login Form</title>
   
    <script>
    function validate() {
        var un = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var pw = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var valid = false;
        var unArray = ["admin", "David", "Paul"];
        var pwArray = ["123456789", "111", "911"];
        for (var i = 0; i < unArray.length; i++) {
            if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (valid) {
        window.confirm('Login was successful')
        {
window.location.href="logintest.html";
};

            return false;
        }
         if (!valid) {
         window.confirm('Login failed')
        {
window.location.href="test.html";
};

            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form action = "{{ request.path }}" method = "POST" >
<div class="p1">
<p> Saudi Electronic University</p> </div>

<div class="container1">

<h1>Instructor Login </h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" id="username" >
      <br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password">
<br>

   <button class="button" id="submit" onclick="validate()" >Submit</button>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the function, maybe i need to have some validation here but i don't know:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    return render_template("test.html")
```

Comment: I guess it's a typo. Just before `window.location.href` you need a closing curly bracket, not an opening one.

Comment: Actually before both you placed a `{` instead of a `}`.

Comment: @Wais Kamal no it is not, i tried tho

Comment: You must prevent the form to be submitted. [They are differents solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Answer (score 0):

There are some bracket issue in your code.
Try this:

```js
if (valid) {
        window.alert('Login was successful');
        window.location.href="logintest.html";
}
else 
{
        window.alert('Login failed');
        window.location.href="test.html";
}
return false;
```

Comment: this does work but when i want to use <a> it won't redirect. <a class="button" id="submit" onclick="validate()" >Submit</a> it gives The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: add href="#" or  href="javascript:void(0)" to the <a>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Instructor Login Form</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    <form id='form'>
        <div class="p1"><p> Saudi Electronic University</p> </div>
        <div class="container1">
            <h1>Instructor Login </h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" id="username" >
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password">
            <br>
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        function validate(event) {
            var un = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var pw = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var valid = false;
            var unArray = ["admin", "David", "Paul"];
            var pwArray = ["123456789", "111", "911"];
            for (var i = 0; i < unArray.length; i++) {
                if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        const form = document.getElementById('form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            if( validate() ) {
                window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
            } else {
                alert('Bad credentials');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you forgot to block the form to be submitted. It is far more easy to do it with eventListener. I changed your solution a little bit to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Instructor Login Form</title>


    <script>
        function validate() {

            console.log("Validate clicked")

            var un = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var pw = document.getElementById("password").value;

            var valid = false;

            var unArray = ["admin", "David", "Paul"];
            var pwArray = ["123456789", "111", "911", "admin"];

            if (unArray.includes(un) && pwArray.includes(pw)) {
                valid = true;
            }

            console.log(valid)

            if (valid) {

                if (window.confirm('Login was successful')) {
                    window.location.href = "logintest.html";
                };

                return false;

            } else {

                if (window.confirm('Login failed')) {
                    window.location.href = "test.html";
                };

                return false;
            }

        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="javascript:void(0)" method="POST">
        <div class="p1">
            <p> Saudi Electronic University</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container1">

            <h1>Instructor Login </h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" id="username">
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password">
            <br>

            <button class="button" onclick="validate();">Submit</button>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

You have to test if

```js
window.confirm('Login failed')
```

was confiremd.